# Diagnostic advice needed: Windows 10 BSODs rendering Surface Book 2 useless

Tags: windows-10, bsod, microsoft-surface

My Surface Book 2 started randomly crashing to different BSODs some months back.
Sometimes, it would crash several times a day and then would behave well for weeks.
Right now I can't even install Windows before it crashes.

**Hardware**

- Surface Book 2 (13.5" Model 1832)
- Core i7-8650U CPU
- 8GB SK HYNIX RAM
- nVidia GeForce 1050 dGPU
- 256GB SK HYNIX BA HFS256GD9TNG SSD

It was running the latest (non-insider) Windows 10 21H1, including drivers and firmware updates.

**BSODs**

I could never manage to recover any memory dumps because of the frequency of the crashes. I tried to analyze them with Windbg preview, but again - BSOD within minutes.
Most frequently, I would get MEMORY_MANAGEMENT, SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION, ATTEMPTED_WRITE_TO_READONLY_MEMORY, KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED, IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL and APC_INDEX_MISMATCH.

**Steps taken so far**

1. chkdsk /f and /r: chkdsk would freeze up if run during Windows startup. Errors were found, but only successfully corrected when I ran chkdsk /r from the Surface recovery USB drive console. This would also take several attempts.
2. Ran all tests on the newest [Intel Processor Diagnostic Tool](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/19792/Intel-Processor-Diagnostic-Tool). No Errors.
3. Restored Windows 10 to the official Microsoft Surface recovery image from USB drive (Version 1909). This initially worked after several attempts, but the system would start BSODing quicker and quicker within the first hour of use.
4. Removed the tablet from the keyboard base (to disconnect dGPU and everything else in the base). No difference.
5. Ran Memtest86 9.3 a total of >16 times (4 passes each). No errors found.
6. Checked S.M.A.R.T. health parameters via Ubtuntu Live USB Drive and Windows. 99% Health reported.
7. Ran Hard Disk Sentinel surface test. No errors reported.
8. Attempted Windows 10 clean install from USB drive (not the recovery image, but the latest Windows 10 ISO). Crashes when starting to copy files.
9. Installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS without issues. Ran it for a day, filled up the SSD with files (mostly games from Steam) to see, if it would crash after some SSD usage. Eventually got several "systemd-udev crashed with SIGABRT in ioctl()" error messages, which disappeared after reverting back from the proprietary nVidia driver to the open source driver.
10. Disabled TPM, SMT and all de-selectable hardware in the UEFI (Docking USB port, Front Camera, Rear Camera, IR Camera, On-board Audio, Wi-Fi & Bluetooth, DGPU). Attempted to install Windows 10, unable to complete the installation due to BSODs.
11. Installed Ubuntu again. Works, again.
12. Tried to install Windows 10 via the surface recovery USB stick again. SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION after clicking "Fully clean the drive"

Now I am totally out of ideas on what the problem is and what I am supposed to do here. The device is not really old, in fact it was replaced last year due to other issues and now it's out of warranty.

This looks an awful lot like a hardware problem to me, but I can't tell what's broken. The only part I could theoretically replace is the SSD (although opening the device is a nightmare).

Any advice on what to do to solve or narrow down the problem is appreciated.

Comment: To me it sounds like a hardware fault, could be anything from poor soldering on the CPU with slightly flakey connection partly dependent on temperature to a failure in the PCH or the dedicated GPU. With so much integrated stuff in the system it is difficult to nail down anything with certainty. That Ubuntu works suggests something about GPU handover is broken and Microsoft auto updating GPU drivers makes it tricky to set up Windows without that side of stuff going. Have you tried installing the absolute generic Windows ISO (not surface image) when not connected to the base?

Comment: @Mokubai Yes, but the bare Windows 10 install doesn't work either (see Point 8). I can't install the ISO without the base attached because the tablet doesn't have any USB ports.

Comment: Urgh. I forgot they assume if you want to do anything useful you need it docked. Maybe you can get a cheap surface Dock (https://www.ebay.co.uk/b/Laptop-Docking-Stations-for-Microsoft-Surface/3709/bn_93581044) and connect to the docking port at the bottom of the tablet? With Ubuntu working it does feel a lot like your problem is in the connection between the tablet and base (or even the iGPU) to me, but that's an expensive part to swap.

Comment: In your list of things you did I don't see Windows' Memory Diagnostic. Type `memory` in Control Panel's search bar.

Comment: @user1292580 No Windows installation means no diagnostics from within Windows. Every Windows installation attempt ends in a BSOD at an early stage.